# why my result is different whit sentiment.ser.gz?

Tags: database, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I have a question, why when I run the model "englishPCFG.ser.gz", I get this result:

(1 (1 (1 (1 Cold) (1 (2 ,) (1 (1 (1 Sterile) (2 And)) (1 Lacking)))) (2 (3 Any) (2 (2 (2 Color) (2 Or)) (3 Warmth)))) (2 .))

and "train.txt" has the following:

(0 (1 (0 (1 Cold) (1 (2 ,) (2 (1 (1 Sterile) (2 And)) (1 Lacking)))) (2 (3 Any) (2 (2 (2 Color) (2 Or)) (3 Warmth)))) (2 .))

why I get a 1 and the file is labeled 0?

please can you help me understand?

Answer (score 0):

The RNN sentiment classifier is a probabilistic / parametric model; it provides no guarantee on exactly reproducing its training data (though it should do fairly well on most of the data).

You should only be worried if you see seriously divergent or unexpected output on your testing data. Otherwise, getting a 1 versus a 0 for a single example is not too concerning.